# After register automatically log in

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, mean.io

After making an account, the user should then be logged in and redirected to the homepage. But somehow it doesn't work.

Because it does go to the homepage but the user is still not logged in. However it does go the to the passport.use() function. (I have logged this on the console). This proves it:

```
POST /api/myTheme/register 200 362 - 54.324 ms

POST /api/login 200 362 - 46.108 ms
```

Below you can see my code:

```
myApp.factory('MyTheme', function($http, $location) {
    return {
        register: function(user) {
            return $http.post('/api/myTheme/register', { 
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password,
                confirmPassword: user.confirmPassword,
                username: user.username,
                name: user.name
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                $http.post('/api/login', {
                    email: user.email,
                    password: user.password
                });

                $location.path( "/" );

            }, function errorCallback(response) {

            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Possible solution**

The post may not have completed by the time I had changed my path. So the possible solution would be using another .then() function. Inside the body of the function I would only have this line of code:

```
$location.path( "/" );
```

But I really don't know how to place the .then() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just chain the `Promise`s:

```
return {
    register: function(user) {
        return $http.post('/api/myTheme/register', { ... })
                .then(function successCallback(response) {
                    return $http.post('/api/login', { ... }
                )
                .then(function successfulLogin(response) {
                    $location.path( "/" );
                })
                .catch(function errorCallback(response) { ... });
    }
};
```

Do notice that you can chain the promises in just one level, which makes your code a bit more readable, and allows you to use `catch` to handle any errors raised by any of those promises.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track when you noticed you are changing the path before the post completes.  You just need to append a `.then()` to the end of your post to /api/login like you did with your post to /api/mytheme/register

Like so

```
myApp.factory('MyTheme', function($http, $location) {
    return {
        register: function(user) {
            return $http.post('/api/myTheme/register', { 
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password,
            confirmPassword: user.confirmPassword,
            username: user.username,
            name: user.name
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $http.post('/api/login', {
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password
            }).then(function(response){  /***********change here***********/
                $location.path( "/" );
            });
        }, function errorCallback(response) {

        });
    }
};
```

});